# How to check what all logging are enabled in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, logs, space-usage

My SharePoint 2013 Web Server`s Log folder is getting full.
I would like to perform assessment to understand:

1. What all logging are enabled currently on the server? Please suggest
   how to achieve it?
2. Are Sharepoint folders within IIS compressed by Default?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Below Powershell command, it will give you level for each category.
`Get-SPLogLevel` and output will be like this( i just copied couple of line.)

```
Area                            Name                            TraceSev   EventSev    
----                            ----                            --------   --------    
Access Services                 Administration                  Medium     Information 
Access Services                 Application Design              Medium     Information 
Access Services                 Application Publishing          Medium     Information
```

You Can also go to `Central Admin > Monitoring > Configure Diagnostic Logging`
On this Page if you expand the each category, you will see the what level it configured.

I dont think, IIS compress the folder.